# select all records from one table and return null values where they do not have another record in second table

Tags: sql

I have looked high and low for this particular query and have not seen it.

We have two tables;   Accounts table and then Visit table.   I want to return the complete list of account names and fill in the corresponding fields with either null or the correct year etc.    this data is used in a matrix report in SSRS.

sample:

```
Acounts:
AccountName  AccountGroup  Location
Brown Jug    Brown Group   Auckland
Top Shop     Top Group     Wellington
Super Shop   Super Group   Christchurch

Visit:
AcccountName  VisitDate   VisitAction
Brown Jug     12/12/2012  complete
Super Shop    1/10/2012   complete
```

I need to select weekly visits and show those that have had a complete visit and then the accounts that did not have a visit.

```
e.g.
Year  Week  AccountName  VisitStatus       for week 10/12/2012 should show
2012    50  Brown Jug    complete
2012    50  Top Group    not complete
2012    50  Super Shop   not complete

e.g.
Year  Week  AccountName  VisitStatus      for week 1/10/2012 should show
2012     2  Brown Jug    not complete
2012     2  Top Group    not complete
2012     2  Super Shop   complete
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Do you want to show only the dates that exist in the data, or do you need to show dates even if they are not in the data?

Comment: See my answer to this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831145/sql-query-complex-inner-joins-and-outer-joins][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831145/sql-query-complex-inner-joins-and-outer-joins

Comment: I unfortunately need all the account names regardless if they are in the visit table.   On those accounts that are in  the visit table I need their data.   the code below is what I am using to produce the current data with accounts and visit details but it does not show us the accounts that have not been visited.   accounts that are not also there.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can put the code I am using - using a pvt to get the data.   every time i paste a sample it is too large.

Comment: Perhaps a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) link?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure how `Week` can be `50` for both `1/10/2012` and `10/12/2012`.  Can you explain that part please?

Comment: Sorry - typo on the week number.   I am very new to these sites so I am not sure what to do with a pastebin and I am very limited with internet access a lot of it is blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please correct me if am worng

select to_char(v.visitdate,'YYYY') year,

to_char(v.visitdate,'WW') WEAK,a.accountname,v.visitaction

from accounts a,visit v

where a.accountname=v.ACCCOUNTNAME

and to_char(v.visitdate,'WW')=to_char(sysdate,'WW')

union all

select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY') year,

to_char(sysdate,'WW') WEAK,a.accountname,'In Complete'

from accounts a

where a.accountname not in ( select v.ACCCOUNTNAME

from visit v where to_char(v.visitdate,'WW')=to_char(sysdate,'WW'));

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked well.   Actually it was a close run thing but this was simplier for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer assumes that

A) You want to see every week within a given range, whether any accounts were visited in that week or not.
B) You want to see all accounts for each week
C) For accounts that were visited in a given week, show their actual VisitAction.
D) For accounts that were NOT visited in a given week, show "not completed" as the VisitAction.

If all those are the case then the following query may do what you need.  There is a functioning sqlfiddle example that you can play with here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4aac0/7

```
--First, get all the dates in the current year.
--This uses a Recursive CTE to generate a date 
--for each week between a start date and an end date
--In SSRS you could create report parameters to replace
--these values.
WITH WeekDates AS
(
  SELECT CAST('1/1/2012' AS DateTime) AS WeekDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(WEEK,1,WeekDate) AS WeekDate
  FROM WeekDates
  WHERE DATEADD(WEEK,1,WeekDate) <= CAST('12/31/2012' AS DateTime)
),
--Next, add meta data to the weeks from above. 
--Get the WeekYear and WeekNumber for each week.
--Note, you could skip this as a separate query 
--and just included these in the next query, 
--I've included it this way for clarity
Weeks AS
(
  SELECT
    WeekDate,
    DATEPART(Year,WeekDate) AS WeekYear,
    DATEPART(WEEK,WeekDate) AS WeekNumber
  FROM WeekDates
), 
--Cross join the weeks data from above with the
--Accounts table.  This will make sure that we 
--get a row for each account for each week.  
--Be aware, this will be a large result set 
--if there are a lot of weeks & accounts (weeks * account)
AccountWeeks AS 
(
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM Weeks AS W
  CROSS JOIN Accounts AS A
)
--Finally LEFT JOIN the AccountWeek data from above
--to the Visits table.  This will ensure that we 
--see each account/week, and we'll get nulls for 
--the visit data for any accounts that were not visited
--in a given week.
SELECT 
  A.WeekYear,
  A.WeekNumber,
  A.AccountName,
  A.AccountGroup,
  IsNull(V.VisitAction,'not complete') AS VisitAction
FROM AccountWeeks AS A
LEFT JOIN Visits AS V
ON A.AccountName = V.AccountName
AND A.WeekNumber = DATEPART(WEEK,V.VisitDate)
--Set the maxrecursion number to a number 
--larger than the number of weeks you will return
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Looks good I am only getting those visits that are null and not the visist that have an action.   I will keep working on this, at this stage I have to go off line until tomorrow but I will come back to you.   Restored my faith in forums.